# Etag attribute present but no Cache-control present in HTTP header

Tags: http, caching, etag

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 07:59:40 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Amazon)
Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Jun 2011 07:28:10 GMT
ETag: "68a7f-278-4a65c06e95680"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 632
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

The above is the http headers for a response. It does not have a Cache-control attribute but has an Etag and Last-Modified attribute. How do browsers handle this situation ? For how long the cache is considered fresh now?

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) Section 13.2.4:

> 13.2.4 Expiration Calculations
>
> In order to decide whether a
>   response is fresh or stale, we need to
>   compare its freshness lifetime to its
>   age. The age is calculated as
>   described in section 13.2.3; this
>   section describes how to calculate
>   the freshness lifetime, and to
>   determine if a response has expired.
>   In the discussion below, the values
>   can be represented in any form
>   appropriate for arithmetic operations.
>
> We use the term "expires_value" to
>   denote the value of the Expires
>   header. We use the term
>   "max_age_value" to denote an
>   appropriate    value of the number of
>   seconds carried by the "max-age"
>   directive of    the Cache-Control
>   header in a response (see section
>   14.9.3).
>
> The max-age directive takes
>   priority over Expires, so if max-age
>   is    present in a response, the
>   calculation is simply:
>
> ```
>   freshness_lifetime = max_age_value
> ```
>
> Otherwise, if Expires is present in
>   the response, the calculation is:
>
> ```
>   freshness_lifetime = expires_value - date_value
> ```
>
> Note that neither of these
>   calculations is vulnerable to clock
>   skew,    since all of the information
>   comes from the origin server.
>
> If none of Expires, Cache-Control:
>   max-age, or Cache-Control: s-
>   maxage (see section 14.9.3) appears in
>   the response, and the response    does
>   not include other restrictions on
>   caching, the cache MAY compute    a
>   freshness lifetime using a heuristic.
>   The cache MUST attach Warning    113
>   to any response whose age is more than
>   24 hours if such warning    has not
>   already been added.
>
> Also, if the response does have a
>   Last-Modified time, the heuristic
>   expiration value SHOULD be no more
>   than some fraction of the interval
>   since that time. A typical setting of
>   this fraction might be 10%.
>
> The calculation to determine if a
>   response has expired is quite
>   simple:
>
> ```
>   response_is_fresh = (freshness_lifetime > current_age)
> ```

Comment: I am not still clear of the heuristic used to calculate the expiration time. Please explain the heuristic part with some example. The 10% is applied on what time interval ?

Comment: The heuristic is application-defined, use whatever you want.  The resulting value should not be longer than some fraction of time (10% was just an example) between the time specified in the `Last-Modified` header and the current time.